# Flask validate and upload file to web page to

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, upload, wtforms

I've been attempting to upload and use a file to my web page but continually run into errors. I have searched repeatedly and tried many different solutions with no success. Any direction would be appreciated.

/app/forms.py

```
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    cadfile = FileField('cadfile', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['STEP','STP'], 'Step Files Only')])
    upload = SubmitField('Upload')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = None

    def validate(self):
        initial_validation = super(UploadForm, self).validate()
        if not initial_validation:
            print('Fails')
            return False
        return True
```

This part of the code fails everytime at "not initial_validation", regardless of no file, incorrect file type or correct file type.

/app/routes.py

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if 'cadfile' in request.files:
            cadfile = request.files['cadfile']
            cadfile.save('/app/tmp/' + cadfile.filename)
            print('Success')
        else:
            print('No Go')
        return redirect(url_for('details'))
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

And my html file
/app/templates/index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Let's Do This</h1>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.cadfile }}
            {{ form.upload() }}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to have it print out 'No File' when no file is selected, 'Invalid File Type' when not a STP or STEP file, and 'Success' when file is successfully uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Here is my final code

/app/forms.py

```
class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
   print('called uploadform')
   cadfile = FileField('cadfile', validators=[FileRequired()])
   upload = SubmitField('Upload')
```

/app/routes.py

```
def index():
   form = UploadForm()
   FILE_TYPES = set(['STEP'])
   var.company_id = current_user.company_id
   if form.validate_on_submit():
       print('Validated')
       submit_name = form.cadfile.data.filename
       if '.' in submit_name and submit_name.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in FILE_TYPES:
           print('Yea Baby it is!')
           ...
           code
           ...
           return redirect(url_for('details'))
       else:
           form.cadfile.errors.append('File is not an accepted format')
   return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

/app/templates/index.html

```
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
           <p>
               {{ form.cadfile }}
               {{ form.upload() }}<br>
               {% for error in form.cadfile.errors %}
               <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
               {% endfor %}
           </p>
       </form>
   </body>
```

Thanks